# How to modify spacy tokenizer to split URLs into individual words

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I want to modify the default tokenizer to split URL's into individual words. Here's what I currently have

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.blank('en')
infixes = nlp.Defaults.infixes + [r'\.']
infix_regex = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes)
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = infix_regex.finditer
print(list(nlp('www.internet.com'))) 
# ['www.internet.com']
# want it to be ['www', '.', 'internet', '.', 'com']
```

I'm looking at the [usage examples](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizers) and [source code](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/tokenizer.pyx) for the tokenizer, but I can't work out this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not seeing results you want because url get caught by `URL_MATCH` first (it has [higher precedence](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizers)):

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.blank('en')
txt = 'Check this out www.internet.com'
doc = nlp(txt)
nlp.tokenizer.explain(txt)
```

---

```
[('TOKEN', 'Check'),
 ('TOKEN', 'this'),
 ('TOKEN', 'out'),
 ('URL_MATCH', 'www.internet.com')]
```

One of the possible solutions:

```
nlp.tokenizer.url_match = None
infixes = nlp.Defaults.infixes + [r'\.']
infix_regex = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes)
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = infix_regex.finditer
doc = nlp(txt)
list(doc)
```

---

```
[Check, this, out, www, ., internet, ., com]
```